# creating list of anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

```
 class Simple
    {
        string Company;
        int Count;
        decimal Amount;
    };

 var balance = bal.GroupBy(d => d.Compnay).Select(
                                            cl => new
                    {
                        Company = cl.Key,
                        Count = cl.Count(),
                        Amount = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount)
                    });
 List<Simple> summary = new List<Simple>();

 summary = balance.ToList();
```

here the last line shows error "can not implicitly convert"

the aboe LINQ query returns anonymous type, how to get a List<> object from it,i.e. calling ToList() method.

Comment: What is a `List<> object `? I mean, if you want a list of an anonymous type as your title suggests, why not simply `...ToList()`?

Comment: Calling `.ToList()` on it should work just fine. Have you tried? What was the problem?

Comment: *"i.e. calling ToList() method"* so you have the answer right?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var balance = bal.GroupBy(d => d.Compnay)
                 .Select(cl => new
                 {
                     Company = cl.Key,
                     Count = cl.Count(),
                     Amount = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount)
                 }).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

On the other hand, if you want to get a list of a custom type that you will declare, then you have to follow the below:

```
class CustomType
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
}

var balance = bal.GroupBy(d => d.Compnay)
                 .Select(cl => new CustomType
                 {
                    Company = cl.Key,
                    Count = cl.Count(),
                    Amount = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount)
                 }).ToList();
```

**Note** The second approach doesn't create a list of objects, whose type is an anonymous type. It is a list of objects of type `CustomType`. On the other hand the first approach creates a list of objects, whose type is an anonymous type.

Comment: Should work but i guess OP wants something different(f.e. a `List<Foo>`). Otherwise i don't understand the question since he already knows `ToList`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are 100% right but as he posted the question that was I thought first. I will make an update of my post. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

i think you want something like this:

```
public class CompanyVM
{

public int Company {get;set;}
public int Count {get;set;}
public int Amount {get;set;}
}


var balance = bal.GroupBy(d => d.Compnay).Select(
                                            cl => new CompanyVM
                    {
                        Company = cl.Key,
                        Count = cl.Count(),
                        Amount = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount)
                    }).ToList();
```

### UPDATE:

For your class you have to write:

```
 List<Simple> balance = bal.GroupBy(d => d.Compnay).Select(
                                            cl => new Simple
                    {
                        Company = cl.Key,
                        Count = cl.Count(),
                        Amount = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount)
                    }).ToList<Simple>();
```

Comment: +1 since you're actually on the right path.

Comment: -1 to +1. OP change the question :D

Comment: i was pretty sure he want a List of some type instead of anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign a list of anonymous type to a list of a known type . Even if they have the same properties its not the same type.